# Write a function called stringFromObject that generates a string from an object's key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, helper

I am attempting to Write a function called stringFromObject that generates a string from an object's key/value pairs.

The format should be "key = value, key = value".

Each key/value pair should be separated by a comma and space except for the last pair.

My code so far:

```
    //write function that accepts an obj.
function stringFromObject(obj) {
  let result = "";
  //loop over the object's properties and create a new string
  //return format should be "key = value, key = value"
  for (let i in obj) {
    result += i + ' =' + obj[i];
  }
  result += '';
  //return a string 
  return result;
}

stringFromObject({ a: 1, b: '2' }); 
// "a = 1, b = 2"
```

The output should be `// "a = 1, b = 2"`, however, I return `=> 'a =1b =2'`. I am confused on how I am returning the two keys with values but the comma is omitted? Any suggestions on what to correct?

Answer (score 3):

To put a comma between each entry, it would be nice to have an array of entries that you can `.join`. You can get an array of entries with `Object.entries`, which gives you both the key and its associated value - just concatenate them together with an `=`:

```js
function stringFromObject(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, val]) => `${key} = ${val}`)
    .join(', ');
}

console.log(stringFromObject({ a: 1, b: '2' }));
```

To tweak your existing code, concatenate a `,` after `obj[i]`, and then after the loop, slice off the last two characters - but it's still kinda inelegant IMO:

```js
//write function that accepts an obj.
function stringFromObject(obj) {
  let result = "";
  //loop over the object's properties and create a new string
  //return format should be "key = value, key = value"
  for (let i in obj) {
    result += i + ' = ' + obj[i] + ', ';
  }
  // remove last comma and space
  result = result.slice(0, result.length - 2);
  return result;
}

console.log(stringFromObject({ a: 1, b: '2' }));
```

Comment: @AndreButler To add to this, the exact reason why you didn't get the output you expected is because first of all you added the string `' ='` between characters which contains no space after the equals sign, causing your first problem. You are also never adding a comma to your string anywhere, so you can't expect a comma to show up in your output

Comment: @awarrier99 thank you for the feedback! I was able to run the code and it passed!

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
function stringFromObject (obj) {
let result = "";
for (let i in obj) {
result += `${i} = ${obj[i]}, `;
}
result = result.slice(0, result.length -2);
return result;
}

stringFromObject({ a: 1, b: '2' });
```